# Kaspersky issue and Fatal Javascript error when using phpMyAdmin Designer

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

My question is about configuring phpMyAdmin on WAMP Server so I can use MySQL Designer in phpMyAdmin.

When my antivirus is on (Kaspersky Total Security), then I cannot see my tables in phpMyAdmin Designer. Do I need to configure something?

[1 Clinking on Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym1Zk.jpg)
 [2 The tables are visible for a a moment or two, and then they vanish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5wc4.jpg)

When I turn off my KTS, then all is fine but now  a Fatal Javascript error is popping up when I click on the Save Page option.

I am using WAMP 3.1.3 with phpMyAdmin 4.79

Also:

> - Server: MySQL (127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP)
> - Server type: MySQL
> - Server version: 5.7.19 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
> - Protocol version: 10
> - Apache version: Apache/2.4.33 (Win64) PHP/7.2.3
> - Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407
> - PHP version: 7.2.3

Comment: Is this solved with the latest phpMyAdmin ?